# .NET Localization - how to set a language?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I've localized my ExportForm into German (de) and Russian (ru) as you can see below:
[image]

If my CultureInfo is German (Austrian-de-AT) then all is OK, I see the format translated into German:

```
string specCult = "de-AT";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(specCult);
```

But I see the English UI with the Russian (ru-RU) CultureInfo

```
string specCult = "ru-RU";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(specCult);
```

Although if I use "ru" instead of the "ru-RU" to create the CultureInfo it works:

```
string specCult = "ru";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(specCult);
```

Could you please help me what might invoke be the problem? Or please point me a direction to investigate the problem.

Comment: Try adding an empty resource file for `ru-RU`. Resources not found in it should fall back to the `ru` file.

Comment: Very strange, but even if I add a non-empty resource file for ru-RU, I am unable to show it by Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU")

Comment: I find this very strange considering that you are not seeing such a problem with "de-AT" (and that it's working for "ru"). In your debugger can you check what Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is set to after you assigned it new CultureInfo("ru-RU")... I wonder if the issue is in the CultureInfo constructor.

Comment: @jams - Answer the question Clafou has.  Your question has only been modified by one person `Rowland Shaw`.

Comment: It is crazy behavior, I also ran into it with jp, another culture that has only one specific cultureinfo.  I think it is a bug in ResourceManager but I never located it.  Stay out of trouble by creating resources for ru-RU instead.

Comment: Creating ans assigning a new CultureInfo("ru-Ru") shows that it was correctly assigned to Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture (as ru-RU). My current Windows locale is Russian, I use Win7.

Answer (score 2):

I've determined the problem: **ru-RU** was selected as a neutral language in my main project assembly settings.

MSDN:
The NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute informs the ResourceManager of the language that was used to display the resources of the neutral culture for an assembly. When it looks up resources in the same culture as the neutral resources language, the ResourceManager automatically uses the resources that are located in the main assembly. It does this instead of searching for a satellite assembly that has the current user interface culture for the current thread. This improves lookup performance for the first resource that you load and can reduce your working set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385967.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ru is the neutral name for the Russian culture, and ru-Ru is the name
of the specific Russian (Russia) culture.

[This is taken from MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> > At startup, the example sets the current culture and the current UI
> >     culture to Russian (Russia) on all systems except those on which the
> >     default system culture is already Russian (Russia). If the default
> >     system culture is already Russian (Russia), the code sets the current
> >     culture and the current UI culture to English (United States).

[Here is other good explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)

> If the resources for a specific culture are not available in the
>   operating system, the resources for the associated neutral culture are
>   used. If the resources for the neutral culture are not available, the
>   resources embedded in the main assembly are used.
>
> The list of locales in the Windows API is slightly different from the
>   list of cultures supported by the .NET Framework. If interoperability
>   with Windows is required, for example, through the p/invoke mechanism,
>   the application should use a specific culture that is defined for the
>   operating system. Use of the specific culture ensures consistency with
>   the equivalent Windows locale, which is identified with a locale
>   identifier that is the same as LCID.

Comment: You need to read about fallbacks. This doesn't address the issue.